# Twilio status callback is not called for trial MMS

Tags: php, callback, twilio, mms

I found another question about callbacks, but that situation is different, both in how it expects the callback to work, and which services it uses, hence this question. ([Twilio Callback URL not Called - PHP & Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550026/twilio-callback-url-not-called-php-wordpress))

The control panel for Twilio Messaging services says:

> Outbound Settings
>
> Make a request to this URL when a message to or from this Messaging
>   Service is completed.

I am able to send a MMS using this configured service.
I am also able to receive MMS/SMS answers, and those generate a callback to my responding web service (which is a simple service that just logs the request data for now.)

However, when I send a MMS using curl, the status callback is never called. It's the exact same URL as the incoming SMS notification, which works.

What am I missing? (Note: I'm configuring a status callback URL in the console, not in the request through curl.)

Here is the request I make to send the message:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/blahblahblah/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+12345678900' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+9876543210' \
-d 'MessagingServiceCid=blahblahblah' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Keep on rocking!' \
-d 'MediaUrl=https://webasset-akm.imvu.com/scene/2314.29/hc-2.1/sDr-t4W83vXXRcWetWbXVjWT5S965bhoB8GKHHt316qYA8nVLvcqD-UaPpSBw75_tn5RMCEIjjwSAMwe5J4yMQRTg92GAnwAEcQmzJPaxuHGh7FKNcj2SCDzZuYJusJsJfvgo_1QabUfCXgVPC7wo8J5NBYdpqRoc3_UtLssRphGGlrdUteIGT4vRv-EIvQBXfbAoSGXlpmqoxbRcohXsEgAkY0OBw_KH4qovzIT9P0eVTFErd_aQcAZPpNWBk1c2Rk9LxhOTqCwYesowSr034TfbRppMhTct0WkpU7JxrOjKFCm0tT0WCu7Dye6IryJRj9yet0vmZrrOzu4jvVuUw==.gif' \
-u blahblah:blahblah
```

(redacted to take the message service cid, account cid, and secret out of the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This seems to be a combination of a couple of things.

First up, you have supplied both a `From` number and a `MessagingServiceCid`. This wouldn't usually work, you should provide one or another.

Second, you actually need to provide a `MessagingServiceSid` (that's an S, not a C).

So what seems to have happened is Twilio has ignored your `MessagingServiceCid` parameter and sent the message using your `From` parameter. Since it didn't come from the messaging service, the callback you set on the service itself will not fire.

So, to fix this you need to remove the `From` parameter and correct to `MessagingServiceSid`.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/blahblahblah/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+12345678900' \
-d 'MessagingServiceSid=blahblahblah' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Keep on rocking!' \
-d 'MediaUrl=https://webasset-akm.imvu.com/scene/2314.29/hc-2.1/sDr-t4W83vXXRcWetWbXVjWT5S965bhoB8GKHHt316qYA8nVLvcqD-UaPpSBw75_tn5RMCEIjjwSAMwe5J4yMQRTg92GAnwAEcQmzJPaxuHGh7FKNcj2SCDzZuYJusJsJfvgo_1QabUfCXgVPC7wo8J5NBYdpqRoc3_UtLssRphGGlrdUteIGT4vRv-EIvQBXfbAoSGXlpmqoxbRcohXsEgAkY0OBw_KH4qovzIT9P0eVTFErd_aQcAZPpNWBk1c2Rk9LxhOTqCwYesowSr034TfbRppMhTct0WkpU7JxrOjKFCm0tT0WCu7Dye6IryJRj9yet0vmZrrOzu4jvVuUw==.gif' \
-u blahblah:blahblah
```

Shout out to [Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51746/brent-schooley) for helping to debug this one.

Comment: Yup, fixing that typo worked! (I only added back the From because the API complained it wasn't there; the real cause of that was of course the typo!)

Comment: @philnash, I am facing a similar problem but it is in "Voice". I am getting a call for my "action" url in my dial verb. But I am not getting the status call back url call at the end in some scenario. Couldn't sort that problem. I am using new Twilio Java SDK for making outbound calls. My TwiML app's status call back url is not called.

Comment: Hi @idarak, it's not easy to answer your question here in the comments. If you can ask a new question and supply the code you are using, what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening, I'll pick it up later and try to help.